# Convert base64 to image

Tags: vba

I have the following 2 functions which give me the base64 of an image

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Function readBytes(strFile As String) As Variant
  Const TypeBinary = 1
  Dim inStream As Object
  ' ADODB stream object used
  Set inStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  ' open with no arguments makes the stream an empty container
  inStream.Open
  inStream.Type = TypeBinary
  inStream.LoadFromFile strFile
  readBytes = inStream.Read()
End Function

Function encodeBase64(arrBytes As Variant) As String
  Dim DM As Object, EL As Object
  Set DM = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
  ' Create temporary node with Base64 data type
  Set EL = DM.createElement("tmp")
  EL.dataType = "bin.base64"
  ' Set bytes, get encoded String
  EL.nodeTypedValue = arrBytes
  encodeBase64 = EL.Text
End Function

Sub test()

TestIt CurrentProject.Path & "\pic.jpg"

End Sub

Function TestIt(strFile As String) As String

  Dim arrBytes As Variant, strRet As String

  arrBytes = readBytes(strFile)
  strRet = encodeBase64(arrBytes)

Dim s As String
Open CurrentProject.Path & "\pic_base64.txt" For Binary As #1
Put #1, 1, strRet
Close #1


End Function
```

I need to convert the following 2 functions to same VBA format as the functions above and add an additional test function which will take the base64 converted image string from the above function and write it back to the image pic.jpg

```
private function decodeBase64(base64)
  dim DM, EL
  Set DM = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
  ' Create temporary node with Base64 data type
  Set EL = DM.createElement("tmp")
  EL.DataType = "bin.base64"
  ' Set encoded String, get bytes
  EL.Text = base64
  decodeBase64 = EL.NodeTypedValue
end function

private Sub writeBytes(file, bytes)
  Dim binaryStream
  Set binaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  binaryStream.Type = TypeBinary
  'Open the stream and write binary data
  binaryStream.Open
  binaryStream.Write bytes
  'Save binary data to disk
  binaryStream.SaveToFile file, ForWriting
End Sub
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Tim, I'm not sure how to declare the 2 functions 'decodeBase64' and 'writeBytes' for example As String or As byte() And I don't know how to use them to read in the 'pic_base64.txt' (produced from the first 2 functions) and convert it back to the 'pic.jpg'